# How to redirect to a facebook page inside app in a webview?

Tags: android, facebook

How can i navigate the user to a facebook fan page inside an Android app?

I try it inside a WebView.
It was worked for 6 months with this url:

```
http://m.facebook.com/pages/OpenGuide/333501443347901
```

Now it is stopped working maybe facebook guys changed something.( YEEES!!! I CAN CODE AGAIN)

So the followins are not working:

```
apps.facebook.com/333501443347901
www.facebook.com/home.php?#!/pages/name-of-site-/333501443347901
http://m.facebook.com/pages/OpenGuide/333501443347901
http://m.facebook.com/333501443347901
```

**So what is the correct URL form to link a facebook page?**

Vanity Url method: (facebook.com/username) is not working for fan pages, only for persons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://m.facebook.com/PAGE_ID should do the trick.

http://m.facebook.com/333501443347901 works just fine for me.